# MySQL FK Cascade - not seeing my mistake

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, cascade

I have read through countless threads on this and am still missing something.
When I delete a row from either table no constraint or cascade occurs.

My goal is to cascade delete any child rows.

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `my_schema`
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1;
USE `my_schema`;

SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_types`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_core_types`;

SET foreign_key_checks = 1;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_core_types`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_core_types` (
  `test_core_type_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `data`                 VARCHAR(100)     NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_core_type_id`))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `test_core_types__data_UNIQUE` ON `test_core_types` (`data` ASC);

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_types`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_types` (
  `test_type_id`      SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_core_type_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED     NOT NULL,
  `name`                 VARCHAR(45)          NOT NULL,
  `is_viewable`          TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED  NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_type_id`))
  ENGINE = InnoDB
  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `test_types__name_UNIQUE` ON `test_types` (`name` ASC);
CREATE INDEX `idx_test_core_type_00` ON `test_types` (`test_core_type_id` ASC);

ALTER TABLE `test_types`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_test_core_type_00`
FOREIGN KEY (`test_core_type_id`)
REFERENCES `test_core_types` (`test_core_type_id`)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Insert:

```
INSERT INTO `test_core_types` (`test_core_type_id`, `data`) VALUES ( 1, 'General');
INSERT INTO `test_types` (`test_type_id`, `test_core_type_id`, `name`, `is_viewable`) VALUES ( 1, 1, 'My General Item', 1);
```

Delete:

```
DELETE FROM `test_core_types` WHERE `test_core_type_id` = 1;
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_core_types`;
/* --> Row Deleted */

SELECT * FROM `test_types`;
/* --> Row still exists */
```

When I perform a delete the row is deleted without errors.
Does not matter which table.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theory:**

For your child table (`test_types`) you have mentioned `ON DELETE CASCADE`; which means when you delete a row from parent table (`test_core_types`); same delete will get cascaded to child table (S) as well and corresponding related row from child table will be deleted.

After your delete query; if you try a select from both table you will find 0 rows present. That's the actual behavior of `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

For Real example check the below mentioned fiddle link

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/33014e/1

Comment: See above, added more info. The child row still exists, not sure why.

Comment: @JonC., that's not correct and not possible. did you checked the fiddle link I have provided in my answer. have created the fiddle from your posted code. it works perfectly. Check that fiddle link. You must be doing something wrong at your side.

Comment: Ah-Ha! You got me thinking... checked my other mysql server and it worked! Bad .cnf configuration on my part. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You've specified a `DELETE` rule of `CASCADE`.

We'd expect a delete from the parent table would succeed, related rows in the table with the foreign key reference will also be deleted. We wouldn't expect any error.

If you want the DELETE operation in your code to throw an error, then define the foreign key reference with a DELETE rule of `RESTRICT`.

---

I recommend you verify that `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` is enabled, and that the foreign key constraint is actually defined (i.e. that the ALTER TABLE statement that added the constraint succeeded. I've never tried specifying `NO ACTION` as an update rule; I know that's the default when no rule is specified, but I always specify either `RESTRICT`, `CASCADE` or `SET NULL`.) Also verify that the table is actually using the InnoDB storage engine.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%foreign_key_checks%' ;
SHOW CREATE TABLE `test_types` ;
```

Comment: Yes, I am looking to cascade delete child rows. I edited the question. The "parent" is delete but this is no effect to the "child" row(s). This is where I am stuck.

Comment: It shows the constraint. I think it's the server. I had the constraints working at one point and started messing with optimizing MySQL, going to reinstall out of curiosity. Thank you for your help!  +1